# How to morphing Multiple object in blender?

Tags: animation, objects, shape-keys

I have multiple meshes they have equal number of vertices.
How to join multiple object as shapes to morphing animation?
 
I know there have method by "join as shapes" to morph one to another, But how to add more object?

Comment: what do you mean by "add more objects". It looks like there are 2 methods, the Shapekeys > Join As Shapes you're talking about, and Shrinkwrap > Assign As Shapekeys. The first one need the other objects to have been modeled from the first one, so that it keeps the same vertices index, and the second one need you to work a sort of retopology I guess.

Comment: the 2 methods, here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBvA2Hduk_w and here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3BSXsrJ-ig